# Interns & Errands

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, story

Going through the to-do list given to him by his bright-eyed boss, a wizard finds the following shopping list:

> a shaving of licorice root
> a red dragon's scale
> a lodestone and iron filings
> a drop of giant slug bile
> a piece of obsidian
> rose petals
> a pair of linked silver rings
> a chip of mica
> a small crystal sphere
> a bit of string and of wood
> a small leather loop

The wizard knows that his boss, as a wizard herself, has issued company-mandated arcane focuses (gorgeous crystals styled after her secret prized possession), so spell components are redundant. After poring over it for a while, he grins, and pulls open his spellbook to study a spell. What spell does he study, and who does he work for?

Hint:

> The answer to "who does he work for?" is generic, not her actual name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Possibly:

> The spell is the Dungeons and Dragons 5E spell "Soul Cage", and he works for a lich.

Explanation of list:

> The items on the list are spell components for D&D 5E. The corresponding spells are:
>
> - Haste
>
>   Aganazzar's Scorcher
>
>   Reverse Gravity
>
>   Vitriolic Sphere
>
>   Erupting Earth
>
>   Sleep
>
>   Telepathy
>
>   Shatter
>
>   Otiluke's Freezing Sphere
>
>   Unseen servant
>
>   Levitate

> Taking the first letter of each spell gives "Harvest Soul".

Finally:

> I couldn't find a "Harvest Soul" spell, so this might be an instruction to the apprentice. Looking at the Necromancy spell list, "Soul Cage" seems like the most likely candidate.

> Liches are interested in collecting souls. "Bright-eyed boss" is a reference to her glowing eye-sockets, and her secret prized possession is her phylactery.

Comment: I was originally going for rot13(vzcevfbazrag onfrq ba gur yvpu'f qrfpevcgvba va gur zbafgre znahny), but from what I could find, your answer is just as valid. You solved the actual puzzle part of it, so here's a check for you!

Comment: @samm82 Kudos for accepting an answer that is not the one you imagined, that's not common